# wordpress images and fonts not loading after uploading site to production

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

In the web inspector, all the paths for images are correct (eg. "src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/images/logo.svg") but none of the SVG files are showing up.

Everything else is working on the site, except the font files are giving me a 404 error, but that might be for a different reason.

Weirder, the images aren't even showing up in the media select tool thing, for example:

[image: broken images]

**EDIT:** site's live at: [privacyhorizon.com](http://privacyhorizon.com)

UPDATE:
I've tried adding

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

to my .htaccess, saw no change :(

Comment: Can you update to include a live demo? Hard to debug issues like this without seeing where the URLs are actually pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your production machine is running a Microsoft IIS 7.0 http server. Htaccess will not work under that environment unless you install certain extensions.

After reviewing your website link, it's evident that svg files are not the only problem. The permalinks are not working either.

To address the permalink issue, paste this in your Web.config file under the system.webServer xml element:

`<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>`

To address the *svg* mime type issue add this in the system.webServer xml element as well:
`<staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>`